# How Do I Loop Text In A Widget?

Tags: android, loops, text, timer, android-widget

I am a noob to android and I am trying to create a news widget that shows a headline and snippet for 30 secs. and then changes to another headline and snippet.  I want the widget to do this in a continuous loop.  So far, i have been only able to display the first headline&snippet.  How do i change the text without calling the alarmManager every 30 secs?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code

```
public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {



    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);


    String tickerheadline="testing";
    String tickerstory="testing";
    for (int i = 0; i < RssReader.rssheadline.size(); i++) {
        tickerheadline = RssReader.rssheadline.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));
        tickerstory = RssReader.rssstory.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() {} 
            }, 30000);

    }

    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline, tickerheadline );
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.story, tickerstory );

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
}
```

EDIT

```
public static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int appWidgetId) {
    final RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {     
    tickerheadline="testing";
    tickerstory="testing";
    for (int i = 0; i < RssReader.rssheadline.size(); i++) {
        tickerheadline = RssReader.rssheadline.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));
        tickerstory = RssReader.rssstory.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));
        context.runOnUiThread(action); //action cannot be resolved as variable
        SystemClock.sleep(30000);

    }
        }
    }).start();

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline, tickerheadline );
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.story, tickerstory );


    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
        }
    };

} }
```

Comment: you can create one new thread and run for loop and update your TextView(UI) text from  UI thread, you can use sleep for 30 sec time interval..

Comment: @visheshchandra thanks for responding. would like place this thread within my updateAppWidget method?

Answer (score 1):

whatever args you are passing in your method you can create a constructor of class and pass on that, And replace "MainActivity.this" to "context". still if you have any doubt then let me know... :)

```
public void updateAppWidget(){
    new YourNewClass().start();
}
private class YourNewClass extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(--,--,--){
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(runnable);
            SystemClock.sleep(30000);
        }
    }
}
private Runnable  runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, the code you presented fires all the runnables at the same time (30 seconds from when the for loop starts).

This is the pattern I generally use:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private static final int NEWS_UPDATE_DELAY = 30*1000;

private Runnable mNewsUpdateHandler = new Runnable() {
     @Override 
     void run() 
     {
          updateNews();
          mHandler.postDelayed(mNewsUpdateHnadler, NEWS_UPDATE_DELAY);
     }
}

private void startNews() 
{
    stopNews();
    mNewsUpdateHandler.run();
}
private void stopNews()
{
    mHandler.removeCallback(mNewsUpdateHandler);    
}
private updateNews()
{
      // your stuff here.
}
```

If don't have one already, you'll need a Service to run that code. Continous appwidget updates can't be done from an Activity, because Activities go away when the user switches to another app..

Answer (score 0):

Now your code look like this. hope it will help you...

```
public static void updateAppWidget(final Activity context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int appWidgetId) {
    final RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String tickerheadline="testing";
            String tickerstory="testing";
            for (int i = 0; i < RssReader.rssheadline.size(); i++) {
                tickerheadline = RssReader.rssheadline.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));
                tickerstory = RssReader.rssstory.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size()-(i+1));

                context.runOnUiThread(action);
                SystemClock.sleep(30000);

//                  Handler handler = new Handler(); 
//                  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
//                       public void run() {} 
//                      }, 30000);

            }
        }
    }).start();

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline, tickerheadline );
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.story, tickerstory );
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Please check my edit.  For some reason runOnUiThread is not seeing the runnable action.  it gives me an error saying action cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @B.Money Please use "final" keyword before "Runnable action = new Runnable() {", Please write like "final Runnable action = new Runnable() {"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the approach to solve your problem. Anyway, `action` cannot be resolved, because it is declared after you want to access it. Try declaring it like this:

```
public static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int appWidgetId) {
    final RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);

    final Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline, tickerheadline);
            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.story, tickerstory);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
        }
    };

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tickerheadline = "testing";
            tickerstory = "testing";
            for (int i = 0; i < RssReader.rssheadline.size(); i++) {
                tickerheadline = RssReader.rssheadline.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size() - (i + 1));
                tickerstory = RssReader.rssstory.get(RssReader.rssheadline.size() - (i + 1));
                context.runOnUiThread(action); //action cannot be resolved as variable
                SystemClock.sleep(30000);

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Also, `runOnUiThread` is method of the class `Activity`, not `Context`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried your suggestion but it didn't have any luck with it.